# I can't find the key of the object in question

Tags: reactjs

The contents of the error are as follows:
Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Look react-dom.development.js

```
 "Objects are not valid as a React child 
(found: " + (Object.prototype.toString.call(newChild) === '[object Object]' ? 'object with keys {' + Object.keys(newChild).join(', ') + '}' : newChild) + "). 
If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead."
```

```
// This is my code

import React, { Component } from "react";

class ResponseCheck extends Component {
  state = {
    state: "waiting",
    message: "Click and Start.",
    result: [],
  };

  timeout;
  startTime;
  endTime;

  onClickScreen = () => {
    const { state } = this.state;
    if (state === "waiting") {
      timeout.current = setTimeout(() => {
        this.setState({
          state: "now",
          message: "Click now",
        });
        this.startTime = new Date();
      }, Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000) + 2000); // 2초~3초 랜덤
      this.setState({
        state: "ready",
        message: "Click when it turns green.",
      });
    } else if (state === "ready") {
      // 성급하게 클릭
      clearTimeout(this.timeout);
      this.setState({
        state: "waiting",
        message: "Too hasty.",
      });
    } else if (state === "now") {
      // 반응속도 체크
      endTime.current = new Date();
      this.setState((prevState) => {
        return {
          state: "waiting",
          message: "Click and Start.",
          result: [...prevState.result, this.endTime, this.startTime],
        };
      });
    }
  };

  onReset = () => {
    this.setState({
      result: [],
    });
  };

  renderAverage = () => {
    const { result } = this.state;
    return result.length === 0 ? null : (
      <>
        <div>Average Time: {result.reduce((a, c) => a + c) / result.length}ms</div>
        <button onClick={this.onReset}>Reset</button>
      </>
    );
  };
  render() {
    const { state, message } = this.state;
    return (
      <>
        <div id="screen" className={state} onClick={this.onClickScreen}>
          {message}
        </div>
        {this.renderAverage()}
      </>
    );
  }
}
export default ResponseCheck;
```

What is the problem? Please help...
I couldn't resolve this problem

The full error code is below.
I have added the whole error in the code

'Look react-dom.development.js' The part above is the same as the number on this line
react-dom.development.js:13231

```
react-dom.development.js:13231 Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
    at throwOnInvalidObjectType (react-dom.development.js:13231)
    at reconcileChildFibers (react-dom.development.js:14133)
    at reconcileChildren (react-dom.development.js:16990)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:17890)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:19049)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:3945)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:3994)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4056)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:23959)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:22771)
```

Comment: Can you share the *actual* error response text, verbatim? Surely there is a stacktrace to tell you where to start looking, a line number?

Comment: Added full error code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy/pasted your code snippet into a *working*, *running* codesandbox and I can't repro your error. The only array in this component is `state.result` and since you are reducing it I don't think it should be triggering a "render" warning like you see.

It does appears as though you were trying to use a react ref for the timers, in your snippet you refer to a `timer.current`, but it isn't a ref, and it should be `this.timer`.

1. Should reference `timer` as `this.timer`, remove the `.current`.
2. Should reference `endTime` as `this.endTime`, remove the `.current`.
3. Push into `result` array the value `this.endTime - this.startTime` so computing the average works.

Code

```
class ResponseCheck extends Component {
  state = {
    state: "waiting",
    message: "Click and Start.",
    result: []
  };

  timeout;
  startTime;
  endTime;

  onClickScreen = () => {
    const { state } = this.state;
    if (state === "waiting") {
      this.timeout = setTimeout(() => { // <-- this.timeout
        this.setState({
          state: "now",
          message: "Click now"
        });
        this.startTime = new Date();
      }, Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000) + 2000); // 2초~3초 랜덤
      this.setState({
        state: "ready",
        message: "Click when it turns green."
      });
    } else if (state === "ready") {
      // 성급하게 클릭
      clearTimeout(this.timeout);
      this.setState({
        state: "waiting",
        message: "Too hasty."
      });
    } else if (state === "now") {
      // 반응속도 체크
      this.endTime = new Date(); // <-- this.endTime
      this.setState((prevState) => {
        return {
          state: "waiting",
          message: "Click and Start.",
          result: [...prevState.result, this.endTime - this.startTime] // <-- correct time value
        };
      });
    }
  };

  onReset = () => {
    this.setState({
      result: []
    });
  };

  renderAverage = () => {
    const { result } = this.state;
    return result.length === 0 ? null : (
      <>
        <div>
          Average Time: {result.reduce((a, c) => a + c) / result.length}ms
        </div>
        <button onClick={this.onReset}>Reset</button>
      </>
    );
  };
  render() {
    const { state, message } = this.state;
    return (
      <>
        <div id="screen" className={state} onClick={this.onClickScreen}>
          {message}
        </div>
        {this.renderAverage()}
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Edit i-cant-find-the-key-of-the-object-in-question]

Comment: Still I am not getting out of the same error "Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead."

Comment: @eeezkim What is the code that you are running doing differently than the code you shared in your snippet or that which I added in my solution that *doesn't* have that error?

Comment: https://github.com/eunjin0212/React-WebGame/tree/master/ResponseCheck 
This link is my full code 
Please check if it is correct

Comment: @eeezkim I see your repo has the same code as my solution. What are you using to run your code? I didn't see a `start` script in your package.json file. Did you use create-react-app? Looks like you run `app.js` from the `dist` directory, was this build artifact updated with the new changes? (*must be, it was updated 21 minutes ago*). Can you try creating your own sandbox and test your code?

Comment: No i haven't used create-react-app. I installed babel and webpack. Delete it and try again.